# CSS divs floating - move div

Tags: css, html, css-float

please, could you help me with floating divs? I have this html structure for the divs:
http://pastebin.com/sBLbfTv1  and I want to move div with button under div with categories... as it is on the image.

**Screenshot:**

[image: div move]

Here is css file: http://pastebin.com/CC4umrgH

Please, help. Thank you!

Comment: You should specify that you cannot change the HTML structure in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with two divs that will work as columns floated.
Then just put in each column what you want:

```
<form>
    <div class="leftColumn">
        <div class="fieldsetMain main"></div>
        <div class="fieldstMain minor"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
        <div class="fieldsetMain main"></div>
        <div class="fieldstMain minor"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the CSS has to be:

```
.leftColumn { float: left; width: 80%; }
.rightColumn { float: left; width: 20%; }
.leftColumn fielsetMain, .rightColumnfieldsetMain { position: relative; }
```

Comment: I know, that I can do it like this, but because of Symfony... I can´t make this structure and I have to use structure I posted... But thank you!

Comment: Ok, a solution could be... if the fieldsetMain main on the right has a fixed height. You can position fieldsetMain main and fieldsetMain minor of the right side with position: absolute; and right: 0px; And defining the top of the minor as equal or superior to the height of the main.

Comment: there is problem, that it had to be variable, I can´t use fixed height :/ last choice is using of jQuery, but if it could be possible, I want to use CSS

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s94R7/)** of the structure you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="c1">
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
    <div class="c3">
    </div>
    <div class="c4">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont{
    float: left;
}
.c1{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.c2{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.c3{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
.c4{
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**Another option** is setting the position of the right-bottom div to absolute:

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
right: 0px;
```

**[Your HTML code with new CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/mV8L3/)**

I'm assuming that your top-right div height is fixed (100px in the example). But it's bad practice, you should avoid it and find a way to control your HTML structure.

Comment: I know, that I can do it like this, but I have to use HTML I posted in my question and I can´t edit it.

Comment: You need to specify that when you're asking a question. I'm not familiar with Symfony but it doesn't make sense you can't control your HTML structure.

Comment: I can control HTML structure, but just a bit. It makes this code, because I have template for form, and I include there other form so it made this code... it is quite hard to explain...

Comment: I edited my answer and added another solution that does not require changing your HTML.

Comment: It looks good. Just one problem is, that heights aren´t fixed.